How to find the resonant sound frequencies of an inflatable ball?
My family and I were in the car today along with a roughly 1 meter diameter inflated yoga ball. I noticed that the ball seemed to resonate and amplify certain frequencies as people were speaking, especially that of a young boy and a baby’s cry.
How might I estimate the resonant audio frequencies for an inflated, thin-walled rubber sphere?

Were the boy and baby in the back seat, and the ball behind them? Perhaps the ball was reflecting sound. Perhaps being closer increased the reflection.

Yes, but the sound had the distinct “selective frequency” nature of resonance. And even if it wasn’t really resonance, it got me thinking about an interesting question of how to find the resonant frequencies in the first place!

You might like this video from Steve Mould - Balloons look really weird when they resonate

You might want to read this paper. The approximation one would usually follow is to treat the yoga ball (or basketball) as a spherical cavity, and the fluid (air) inside to follow the wave equation for the pressure perturbation field
$$\nabla^2 p-\frac{1}{c^2}\frac{\partial^2 p}{\partial t^2}=0. $$
Under some assumptions, it can be shown that the pressure field at the boundary $R$ follows
$$\frac{\partial p}{\partial r}(r=R) = 0.$$
In a spherical geometry, the solution to the wave equation using separation of variables implies that the radial part of the solution (call it $\mathcal{R}$)
is a spherical Bessel function of the first kind
$$\mathcal{R}(r) = j_l(kr),$$
and so if you impose the above boundary condition, you obtain this equation
$$\frac{d}{dr}\left(j_l(kR)\right)=0 \to k_{nl}=\frac{z_{nl}}{R}, $$
where $z_{nl}$ is the n-th zero of the derivative of the l-th spherical Bessel function of the first kind. By the way, these derivatives hold
$$j_l'(z) =j_{l-1}-\frac{l+1}{z}j_l,$$
so the zeroes of the derivatives are all conected to the zeroes of the spherical Bessel functions, call them $x_{nl}$. Since $\omega = kc$, then
$$ f_{nl}= \frac{z_{nl}c}{2\pi R}.$$

This result looks a bit counter intuitive - you would expect that the frequency depends on the pressure difference and the elasticity module of the rubber.

@chth This approximation is quite simple as it only assumes a spherical cavity , without considering its properties beyond the boundary conditions, and it also ignores any outside influence. But as you can see in Table 1 of the paper I linked, the theoretical frequencies are generally close to the measured ones.

Interesting - I wonder if a basketball is more appropriate to model as a spherical cavity than a rubber yoga ball, but in any case this paper and approach seem promising. Thank you!
